# Thread updating wallpaper stopped when leaving app?

Tags: java, android, background-process, wallpaper

I want to program an app which updates the device background every few ms (this way i want to display a gif; first idea I had any better ones?) and I wonder if this would work with a Thread or a Runnable which updates the wallpaper every few ms.
But won't the Thread or Runnable be stopped/destroyed when I leave the app?

Do you guys have any better ideas for displaying a gif file?

Backgrondinfo: I want to use a gif as wallpaper and a picture as lockscreen and the playstore apps can't handle that. (Got root proviliges to place picture as lockscreen)
Also it's a good practice for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

To do this type of things, There's a separate  concept called Service . Service is process which runs even after a Task is destroyed() . To know more about Service's check out devlopers.google.com